# Is there a way to group fonts within Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-management

I've done searches on here to find an answer to my question, and while I have found other questions asking similar questions, but every answer was using a third party program to disable certain fonts.

My question is, **is there a way to organize fonts specifically in Adobe Illustrator?**

For example, if I select my fonts, they are already in groups that Illustrator created. It starts out with a list of all the fonts I have installed, then a line followed by other fonts that are in foreign languages, and then other lines after that.

I don't want to ever disable a font, but sometimes if I'm trying to find a font, I'll start at the top and then click the font drop down and start pressing the down arrow to cycle through my fonts.

There are some fonts that when I select it, the name goes away in the drop down list (the font still works) and the list defaults back to the Myriad Pro font that it always starts at.

So, if there would be a way for me to create a list of those fonts that I can't scroll through, and put them below the rest of the fonts, that would save me a HUGE headache in going through my font search.

Comment: I'm using a PC, sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Hi Protocol Zero, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeking is indeed impossible.

Adobe applications list fonts **alphabetically**, then by encoding. So you'll find cyrillic fonts listed in a separate section than Latin fonts. But still ordered alphabetically within that section. The only caveat to this is the "recent fonts" list that Adobe throws at the top of the menu (but *still* doesn't start any menu click with any of those selected).

**Changing how the internal font lists are configured means you'd have to change the underlying code base for the application.** So, no, you can't do what you are asking.

Even third party font managing applications won't reorder the menus within Adobe applications any longer (they used to years and years ago - i.e. ATM Deluxe).

Activating/deactivating fonts is the *only* method to change the font listings.

Comment: It would be better if you used not possible instead of impossible. Since it is in fact possible for adobe to do this,  just does not care enough to do so

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options with PC:
1. Enable and disable each font in the font folder one by one
2. Download a font managing software - [here's an article about some of them](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/05/25-font-management-tools-reviewed/) and then within the software group you fonts and enable/disable certain groups.
*In mac computers the font managing software is built in and it's called font book*

Comment: I've looked into the second option already, and I don't actually want to disable any fonts. I still want to be able to access the fonts causing problems, just keep them in a separate list. I'm guessing that maybe what I'm seeking is impossible?

Comment: The font's managers are pretty easy to use and you can enable/disable groups while working. I don't have too many "problematic" fonts but that's what I do when I can only use web fonts or only free fonts, etc. Enabling and disabling fonts is pretty simple and easy.